# cx_Freeze does not include .py files from subdirectories

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm building a program with Python 3.3, Pyside and lxml amongst others. cx_Freeze was working like a charm until I starting sorting my modules into subdirectories for neatness. cx_Freeze works but reports the modules as missing and the output .exe file fails to load, but there are no issues opening the program with the .py file.

My folder structure is simple and only has 2 sub-folders called parsers and constants.

The cx_Freeze documentation allows for adding a path variable, but this doesn't search for the modules. All help appreciated.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable

includefiles = ['open.png', 'appicon.png']
includes = []
excludes = ['Tkinter']
packages = ['lxml._elementpath','lxml.etree']
build_exe_options = {'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = 'Config-Sheets',
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'Convert system configuration into .XLSX files',
    author = 'ZZZ',
    author_email = 'XXX@YYY.com',
    options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options }, 
    executables = [Executable('main.py', base=base)]
)
```

Results in and an exe that can't run.

```
Missing modules:
...
? parsers.parsercelerra imported from main__main__
? parsers.parserVPLEX imported from main__main__
? parsers.parserrain imported from main__main__
```

Comment: I think that cx_Freeze should not make such a bad job in including files from a sub directory. There is a sample of a [relative import](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/src/e7d62bc3c7fd073b4a6c3f5206d47110e95e062c/cx_Freeze/samples/relimport/?at=default) included in the official source code (cx_Freeze / cx_Freeze / samples / relimport / ). Test if you can recreate this behavior.

Comment: Where are the directories? If they're packages that can be imported, cx_freeze should be able to find them.

Comment: They are simply nested 1 level underneath the folder containing the main.py

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to include your packages very simply:

```
packages = ['lxml._elementpath','lxml.etree', 'parsers', 'constants']
```

Of course the directories must contain `__init__.py` in order to be considered packages.

If this doesn't achieve the desired effect then it would be useful to see the import mechanism used in `main.py` to pull these files in. If it's doing anything other than a straightforward `import` (or `from x import`) this can give cx_Freeze problems finding it.

Answer (score -2):

You should include your `.py` files in the `setup.py` script. If the file is not a part of Python itself, cx_freeze needs to know that you want those files included. You should add your extra `.py` files with their paths to the `includefiles` list. For instance:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable

includefiles = ['open.png', 'appicon.png', 'parsers\xtra_file1.py','constants\xtra_file2.py']
includes = []
excludes = ['Tkinter']
packages = ['lxml._elementpath','lxml.etree']
build_exe_options = {'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}

...
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: This did not work for me. Adding the path of the files to the includefiles parameter only resulted in the .py files being copied as is into a folder in the build directory without being compiled.